# N-Grams to array

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

For my thesis i am working on a machine learning project using Python which includes feature extraction from text. As a start I am trying to implement bi-grams using sci-kit learn.

Right now, when i process my data trough `Countvectorizer`, I get an array of just `1`'s and sometimes a bit more. E.g.:

```
`[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]`
```

I want to use these bi-grams to predict my target variable, which is categorical. 
When i now execute my code, Python returns that the shape of my two arrays are not identical.

```
`[[1 3 2 ..., 1 1 1]] [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]`
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? I am using this command for the bi-grams. The first part is a loop for every text (film plot) in the dataset.

```
        plottext = [ row[8] ]
        wordvec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
        plotvec = wordvec.fit_transform(plottext).toarray()
        matrix_terms = np.array(wordvec.get_feature_names())
        matrix_freq = np.asarray(plotvec.sum(axis=0)).ravel()
        final_matrix = np.array([matrix_terms,matrix_freq])
        target = { 'Age': row[4] }
        data.append((final_matrix, target))
# Convert categorial target variable to Y
(X, Ycat) = zip(*data)
vec = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
Y = vec.fit_transform(Ycat)
#Extract textual features from plot
return (X, Y)
```

The error message i get

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,830) into shape (2)
```

Comment: Please post some of the code after `plotvec = wordvec.fit_transform(plottext).toarray()`.

Comment: I've added more code, thank you.

Comment: Where is the error thrown? The message kinda looks like the X and Y that your classifier gets might have different lengths. Try something like `print len(X), len(Y)`.

Comment: The error is thrown in when i load it into a classifier. The length of the X and Y is equal.